# How does Linux reads "real files" and "virtual files"?

Tags: linux, filesystems, proc

I have found out that in Linux there are "real files" and there are "virtual files", real files are files that resides on the hard disk, while virtual files are just data represented by the kernel as files.

For example, the files in the `/proc` directory are virtual files.

I want to understand how a function like `read()` knows how to read a real file and how to read a virtual file. I have created the following diagram to show my understanding of this subject, please correct me if I am wrong about my understanding:

[image]

Comment: [`read(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/read.2.html) is a system call. Once the userland process calls `read()` control passes to the kernel, who of course knows perfectly well where to go for the data; the source can be a filesystem backed by persistent local storage, or a socket, or a FIFO, or a named pipe, or, yes, a virtual file.

Comment: @AlexP  I believe that `read()` issues a system call, but it is not itself a system call.

Comment: @AlexP `read()` is a POSIX-standard function. Per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):  "The *read()* **function** shall attempt to read *nbyte* bytes ...  if *nbyte* is zero, the *read()* **function** may detect and return errors ..."  As @ Paul says, it may issue a system call, but `read()` itself is a *function*.

Answer (score 5):

In VFS layer all files are virtual (it was actually invented by SunOS engineers to tie UFS (disk-based) and NFS (network-based) filesystem).

Each open `file` has table of functions `f_op` that provide implementations for common routines (some of them may be generic) and each `inode` has an attached `address_space` object that also has table of C functions (`a_ops`) containing necessary implementations. The sequence is this:

1. `sys_read()`: Application initiates file reading using system call
2. Call is passed to VFS stack top layer (`vfs_read()`)
3. Call is passed to filesystem driver using `file->f_op->read()` or `do_sync_read()` or `new_sync_read()`
4. If file is opened in direct input output mode, appropriate function (`a_ops->direct_IO()`, `ext4_direct_IO()` for `ext4`) is called and data is returned
5. If page is found in page cache, data is returned   `file_get_page()`
6. If page was not found in page cache, it is read from filesystem using  `a_ops->readpage()`, which is implemented by `ext4_readpage()` from `ext4` driver
7. VFS stack creates block input-output request using `submit_bio()`

<sup>From http://myaut.github.io/dtrace-stap-book/kernel/fs.html, it is a bit outdated as VFS stack was refactored a bit after I'd written this</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to give an exhaustive answer on this by any means...

You're essentially correct, except for one important separation: **read()** asks the *kernel* what a file descriptor contains, the *kernel* handles the rest.  Whether it's a physical filesystem, a network filesystem, a virtual filesystem (/proc, /sys, ...) is irrelevant to **read()**.  The kernel has underlying code to service the request (or not), which is what you're referring to as a driver.